# SQL Update from One Table to Another Based on a ID Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-update

I have a database with `account numbers` and `card numbers`. I match these to a file to `update` any card numbers to the account number so that I am only working with account numbers.

I created a view linking the table to the account/card database to return the `Table ID` and the related account number, and now I need to update those records where the ID matches the Account Number.

This is the `Sales_Import` table, where the `account number` field needs to be updated:

| LeadID | AccountNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 147 | 5807811235 |
| 150 | 5807811326 |
| 185 | 7006100100007267039 |

And this is the `RetrieveAccountNumber` table, where I need to update from:

| LeadID | AccountNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 147 | 7006100100007266957 |
| 150 | 7006100100007267039 |

I tried the below, but no luck so far:

```
UPDATE [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import] 
SET    [AccountNumber] = (SELECT RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
                          FROM   RetrieveAccountNumber 
                          WHERE  [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import]. LeadID = 
                                                RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID)
```

It updates the card numbers to account numbers, but the account numbers get replaced by `NULL`

Answer (score 1704):

I believe an `UPDATE FROM` with a `JOIN` will help:

### MS SQL

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import
SET
    Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
    Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
    RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID;
```

### MySQL and MariaDB

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import SI,
    RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
SET
    SI.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
WHERE
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID;
```

Comment: You might want to use the table alias in the UPDATE clause, otherwise it will cause problems if you self join the table at any point.

Comment: In the set clause you should change `SI.AccountNumber` to just `AccountNumber` otherwise it will fail.

Comment: MS-Access uses a different UPDATE with JOIN Statement. Have a look at: http://www.sql-und-xml.de/sql-tutorial/update-aktualisieren-der-zeilen.html

Comment: You can't use a table alias in the update clause. I have however updated the sample to reference the updated table directly.

Comment: this seems to be fine for mssql but doesn't seem to work in mysql. This seems to do the job though: `UPDATE Sales_Import, RetrieveAccountNumber SET Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber where Sales_Import.LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID;`.  Slightly off topic but may be helpful

Comment: I think there is no need for the inner join. Vonki solution below works:
UPDATE [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import] SET [AccountNumber] = 
RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
FROM RetrieveAccountNumber 
WHERE [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import].LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID

Comment: @Gutti At least in simple cases, the explain plan is the same: Table scans -> hash match -> sort -> update

Comment: @MarkS.Rasmussen You actually can use an alias in both the update and set clauses. "update alias set alias.column = alias2.column from table1 as alias join table2 as alias2 ..." works.

Comment: You could also use JOIN in MySQL `UPDATE Sales_Import JOIN RetrieveAccountNumber ON Sales_Import.LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID SET Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber`

Comment: This works better than the answer below as the INNER JOIN solves the 'must declare the scalar variable' error when using a user defined table type as a parameter for a stored procedure.

Comment: Set should be under the join on

Comment: this is postgres: UPDATE table_a t1
SET col_tb1 = t2.col_tb2
FROM table_b t2
WHERE t1.col_id = t2.col_id

Answer (score 348):

The simple Way to copy the content from one table to other is as follow:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

You can also add the condition to get the particular data copied.

Comment: This works, but you don't need table2 in the FROM

    UPDATE table2 
    SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
    table2.col2 = table1.col2,
    ...
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid

Comment: This didn't worked, but
UPDATE table2, table1
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1,
...
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
(mysql and phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 172):

For SQL Server 2008 + Using `MERGE` rather than the proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax has some appeal.

As well as being standard SQL and thus more portable it also will raise an error in the event of there being multiple joined rows on the source side (and thus multiple possible different values to use in the update) rather than having the final result be undeterministic.

```
MERGE INTO Sales_Import
   USING RetrieveAccountNumber
      ON Sales_Import.LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET AccountNumber = RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber;
```

Unfortunately the choice of which to use may not come down purely to preferred style however. The implementation of `MERGE` in SQL Server has been afflicted with various bugs. Aaron Bertrand has compiled a list of [the reported ones here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: MERGE is great, but it's worth noting that it will not work if you're using a linked server `The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.`.

Comment: The arguments for using MERGE (including those in [the post from sqlblog.com](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2008/03/10/lets-deprecate-update-from.aspx) linked above) might be compelling, but one thing to consider might be that [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx): _...MERGE statement works best when the two tables have a complex mixture of matching characteristics...When simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improved performance and scalability can be achieved with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements_

Comment: I realize it's dated now, but the linked post from Bertrand says, "*However, MERGE originally shipped with several "wrong results" and other bugs... some of which continue to exist even in the early preview releases of SQL Server 2014... **I have been recommending that - for now - people stick to their tried and true methods of separate statements.***" (emph mine) See also his comment on `January 26, 2014 - 8:28:58 PM`. @MartinSmith -- Any reason to suspect things are better now?

Comment: FWIW, does not work with Access shipped with MS Office 365 Pro Plus.

Comment: @jkp1187 This question is tagged SQL Server. So RE: FWIW - approximately zero.

Comment: @MartinSmith For people with limited experience, who happened upon this page thanks to results from a search engine, it's non-zero.

Comment: Stop using Access tho.

Answer (score 160):

Generic answer for future developers.

## SQL Server

```
UPDATE 
     t1
SET 
     t1.column = t2.column
FROM 
     Table1 t1 
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

## Oracle (and SQL Server)

```
UPDATE 
     t1
SET 
     t1.colmun = t2.column 
FROM 
     Table1 t1, 
     Table2 t2 
WHERE 
     t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

## MySQL

```
UPDATE 
     Table1 t1, 
     Table2 t2
SET 
     t1.column = t2.column 
WHERE
     t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: Of note at least for SQL Server, use the alias rather than the table name in the top update clause (`update t1...` rather than `update Table1...`)

Comment: Does not work in Oracle: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: What is the suggested solution for ORA-00933?

Comment: the oracle variant did not work for me

Comment: The Oracle SQL answer is obviously wrong, you can only use Merge Into or correlated subquery to achieve this

Comment: Can you correct it pls? This answer was years ago.

Answer (score 74):

For PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE Sales_Import SI
SET AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
WHERE RAN.LeadID = SI.LeadID;
```

Comment: The mistake which I am doing is:

SET SI.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber.

Still, I wonder why it is wrong in postgresql? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 42):

Seems you are using MSSQL, then, if I remember correctly, it is done like this:

```
UPDATE [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import] SET [AccountNumber] = 
RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
FROM RetrieveAccountNumber 
WHERE [Sales_Lead].[dbo].[Sales_Import].LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID
```

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem with `foo.new` being set to `null` for rows of `foo` that had no matching key in `bar`. I did something like this in Oracle:

```
update foo
set    foo.new = (select bar.new
                  from bar 
                  where foo.key = bar.key)
where exists (select 1
              from bar
              where foo.key = bar.key)
```

Comment: Why is the *WHERE EXISTS* required?

Comment: Because each row in foo not having a match in bar ended up being null, because the select statement produced null. Hope this was clearer than my first attempt at explaining it.

Comment: check this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match#answer-224807

Answer (score 38):

Here's what worked for me in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [AspNetUsers] SET

[AspNetUsers].[OrganizationId] = [UserProfile].[OrganizationId],
[AspNetUsers].[Name] = [UserProfile].[Name]

FROM [AspNetUsers], [UserProfile]
WHERE [AspNetUsers].[Id] = [UserProfile].[Id];
```

Answer (score 32):

For MySql that works fine:

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import SI,RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
SET
    SI.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
WHERE
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID
```

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for the responses. I found a solution tho.

```
UPDATE Sales_Import 
SET    AccountNumber = (SELECT RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
                          FROM   RetrieveAccountNumber 
                          WHERE  Sales_Import.leadid =RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID) 
WHERE Sales_Import.leadid = (SELECT  RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID 
                             FROM   RetrieveAccountNumber 
                             WHERE  Sales_Import.leadid = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID)
```

Comment: Whether or not the code here works, you should probably look at the other two solutions posted. They are much clearer and much less prone to error as well as almost certainly faster.

Comment: Just a note on this solution, UPDATE...FROM is proprietary therefore, if you cannot use the MERGE statement because you are using SQL 2005 or earlier, this is an ANSI-compliant method of performing updates with a table source in MSSQL.  Source: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2008/03/10/lets-deprecate-update-from.aspx

Comment: the only solution that works for me because its a standard SQL update statement (UPDATE SET WHERE), thanks alot

Answer (score 21):

In case the tables are in a different databases. (MSSQL)

```
update database1..Ciudad
set CiudadDistrito=c2.CiudadDistrito

FROM database1..Ciudad c1
 inner join 
  database2..Ciudad c2 on c2.CiudadID=c1.CiudadID
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the following block of query to update Table1 with Table2 based on ID:

```
UPDATE Sales_Import, RetrieveAccountNumber 
SET Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber 
where Sales_Import.LeadID = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadID;
```

This is the **easiest way** to tackle this problem.

Comment: This query is good, but until the development is done, it will block the whole table.

can we make any change here, to convert it to a row-based lock only?

Answer (score 16):

MS Sql

```
UPDATE  c4 SET Price=cp.Price*p.FactorRate FROM TableNamea_A c4
inner join TableNamea_B p on c4.Calcid=p.calcid 
inner join TableNamea_A cp on c4.Calcid=cp.calcid 
WHERE c4..Name='MyName';
```

Oracle 11g

```
        MERGE INTO  TableNamea_A u 
        using
        (
                SELECT c4.TableName_A_ID,(cp.Price*p.FactorRate) as CalcTot 
                FROM TableNamea_A c4
                inner join TableNamea_B p on c4.Calcid=p.calcid 
                inner join TableNamea_A cp on c4.Calcid=cp.calcid 
                WHERE p.Name='MyName' 
        )  rt
        on (u.TableNamea_A_ID=rt.TableNamea_B_ID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        Update set Price=CalcTot  ;
```

Answer (score 11):

update from one table to another table on id matched

```
UPDATE 
     TABLE1 t1, 
     TABLE2 t2
SET 
     t1.column_name = t2.column_name 
WHERE
     t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: In SQL Server v18, it does not seem to allow a second table in the UPDATE. It complains about the comma and wants a SET statement. Perhaps this solution works in a different database.

Answer (score 8):

The below SQL someone suggested, does NOT work in SQL Server. This syntax reminds me of my old school class:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

All other queries using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` are not recommended. NULLs show up because OP compares entire dataset with smaller subset, then of course there will be matching problem. This must be fixed by writing proper SQL with correct `JOIN` instead of dodging problem by using `NOT IN`. You might run into other problems by using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` in this case.

My vote for the top one, which is conventional way of updating a table based on another table by joining in SQL Server. Like I said, you cannot use two tables in same `UPDATE` statement in SQL Server unless you join them first.

Comment: I can only say that in SQL Server 2017 this works perfectly well. Just as a note for future people coming by. No need to join them.

Answer (score 7):

This is the easiest and best have seen for Mysql and Maria DB

```
UPDATE table2, table1 SET table2.by_department = table1.department WHERE table1.id = table2.by_id
```

Note: If you encounter the following error based on your Mysql/Maria DB version "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences"

Then run the code like this

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE table2, table1 SET table2.by_department = table1.department WHERE table1.id = table2.by_id
```

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing the other answers, there're 4 variants of how to update target table using data from another table only when "match exists"

Query and sub-query:

```
update si
set    si.AccountNumber = (
    select ran.AccountNumber 
    from   RetrieveAccountNumber ran
    where  si.LeadID = ran.LeadID
)
from Sales_Import si
where exists (select * from RetrieveAccountNumber ran where ran.LeadID = si.LeadID)
```

Inner join:

```
update si
set si.AccountNumber = ran.AccountNumber
from Sales_Import si inner join RetrieveAccountNumber ran on si.LeadID = ran.LeadID
```

Cross join:

```
update si
set si.AccountNumber = ran.AccountNumber
from Sales_Import si, RetrieveAccountNumber ran
where si.LeadID = ran.LeadID
```

Merge:

```
merge into Sales_Import si
using RetrieveAccountNumber ran on si.LeadID = ran.LeadID 
when matched then update set si.accountnumber = ran.accountnumber;
```

All variants are more-less trivial and understandable, personally I prefer "inner join" option. But any of them could be used and developer has to select "better option" according to his/her needs

From performance perspective variants with join-s are more preferable:
[image]

Comment: Successfully used the cross join example. As the source was a backup and the tables had the same names I needed to use alias names but it worked beautifully then. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

it works with postgresql

```
UPDATE application
SET omts_received_date = (
    SELECT
        date_created
    FROM
        application_history
    WHERE
        application.id = application_history.application_id
    AND application_history.application_status_id = 8
);
```

Answer (score 4):

update within the same table:

```
  DECLARE @TB1 TABLE
    (
        No Int
        ,Name NVarchar(50)
        ,linkNo int
    )

    DECLARE @TB2 TABLE
    (
        No Int
        ,Name NVarchar(50)
        ,linkNo int
    )

    INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES(1,'changed person data',  0);
    INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES(2,'old linked data of person', 1);

INSERT INTO @TB2 SELECT * FROM @TB1 WHERE linkNo = 0


SELECT * FROM @TB1
SELECT * FROM @TB2


    UPDATE @TB1 
        SET Name = T2.Name
    FROM        @TB1 T1
    INNER JOIN  @TB2 T2 ON T2.No = T1.linkNo

    SELECT * FROM @TB1
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought this is a simple example might someone get it easier,

```
        DECLARE @TB1 TABLE
        (
            No Int
            ,Name NVarchar(50)
        )

        DECLARE @TB2 TABLE
        (
            No Int
            ,Name NVarchar(50)
        )

        INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES(1,'asdf');
        INSERT INTO @TB1 VALUES(2,'awerq');


        INSERT INTO @TB2 VALUES(1,';oiup');
        INSERT INTO @TB2 VALUES(2,'lkjhj');

        SELECT * FROM @TB1

        UPDATE @TB1 SET Name =S.Name
        FROM @TB1 T
        INNER JOIN @TB2 S
                ON S.No = T.No

        SELECT * FROM @TB1
```

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to update a table based on the column value not being found in another table.

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.column = 'some_new_val' WHERE table1.id IN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
                SELECT table1.id
                FROM  table1 
                LEFT JOIN table2 ON ( table2.column = table1.column ) 
                WHERE table1.column = 'some_expected_val'
                AND table12.column IS NULL
        ) AS Xalias
)
```

This will update a table based on the column value being found in both tables.

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.column = 'some_new_val' WHERE table1.id IN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
                SELECT table1.id
                FROM  table1 
                JOIN table2 ON ( table2.column = table1.column ) 
                WHERE table1.column = 'some_expected_val'
        ) AS Xalias
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**try this :**

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.AccountNumber = Table_B.AccountNumber ,
FROM
    dbo.Sales_Import AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN dbo.RetrieveAccountNumber AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.LeadID = Table_B.LeadID 
WHERE
    Table_A.LeadID = Table_B.LeadID
```

Answer (score 2):

**MYSQL** (This is my preferred way for restoring **all** specific column `reasonId` values, based on primary key `id` equivalence)

```
UPDATE `site` AS destination  
INNER JOIN `site_copy` AS backupOnTuesday 
      ON backupOnTuesday.`id` = destination.`id`
SET destdestination.`reasonId` = backupOnTuesday.`reasonId`
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11g

```
merge into Sales_Import
using RetrieveAccountNumber
on (Sales_Import.LeadId = RetrieveAccountNumber.LeadId)
when matched then update set Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RetrieveAccountNumber.AccountNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle SQL try using alias

```
UPDATE Sales_Lead.dbo.Sales_Import SI 
SET SI.AccountNumber = (SELECT RAN.AccountNumber FROM RetrieveAccountNumber RAN WHERE RAN.LeadID = SI.LeadID);
```

Comment: You answer seems the same as lot of others

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one extra thing.

Don't update a value with the same value, it generates extra logging and unnecessary overhead. 
See example below - it will only perform the update on 2 records despite linking on 3.

```
DROP TABLE #TMP1
DROP TABLE #TMP2
CREATE TABLE #TMP1(LeadID Int,AccountNumber NVarchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #TMP2(LeadID Int,AccountNumber NVarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #TMP1 VALUES
(147,'5807811235')
,(150,'5807811326')
,(185,'7006100100007267039');

INSERT INTO #TMP2 VALUES
(147,'7006100100007266957')
,(150,'7006100100007267039')
,(185,'7006100100007267039');

UPDATE A
SET A.AccountNumber = B.AccountNumber
FROM
    #TMP1 A 
        INNER JOIN #TMP2 B
        ON
        A.LeadID = B.LeadID
WHERE
    A.AccountNumber <> B.AccountNumber  --DON'T OVERWRITE A VALUE WITH THE SAME VALUE

SELECT * FROM #TMP1
```

Answer (score 0):

##### ORACLE

use

```sql
UPDATE suppliers
SET supplier_name = (SELECT customers.customer_name
                     FROM customers
                     WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customers.customer_name
              FROM customers
              WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

update table1 dpm set col1 = dpu.col1 from table2 dpu where dpm.parameter_master_id = dpu.parameter_master_id;

Answer (score -3):

If above answers not working for you try this

```
Update Sales_Import A left join RetrieveAccountNumber B on A.LeadID = B.LeadID
Set A.AccountNumber = B.AccountNumber
where A.LeadID = B.LeadID
```