# Update multiple columns in a table from another tables data including nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with 6 columns, in one table (the one I want to update) the first three columns are already populated, the other three I just made so they're empty.

Summary table

```
Number, ID, height, weight, volume, density
1        1     5       
2        2     5
3        3     12
```

I have another table fully populated where the same ID is used but the other data fluctuates and it doesn't have the height

Daily table

```
Number, ID, name, weight, volume, density
1       1    c3     23               10
2       2    c17    24.2    1        5
3       3    c12    22      2        6
4       1    c3     21      2
5       2    c17    25               8
```

I want to take the last weight, volume, density values from the Daily table and use them to populate those columns in the Summary table. Both tables have thousands of entries with the daily one close to a million.

Result should be Summary table changes to

```
Number, ID, height, weight, volume, density
1       1     5      21      2   
2       2     5      25               8
3       3     12     22      2        6
```

I can do it bit by bit using info I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition), but I want to do it all at once.
Please assist.

Comment: How do you identify the "last" row in the daily table? I don't see any timestamp or something similar

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they're numbered rows, sorry should be six columns now I see what you mean, I'll edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update summary 
  set weight = t.weight,
      volume = t.volume, 
      density = t.density
from (
  select distinct on (id) id, weight, volume, density
  from daily
  order by id, number desc
) t
where t.id = summary.id;
```

The inner select will only return the rows from the daily table with the highest "number" for each id. For other ways of solving that see [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

Online example: http://rextester.com/AWT29305

Comment: Works well for my needs, nice and simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowing funtion to get the latest entry in your daily table for each ID.  I've tested this in SQL Server, but I believe the syntax for postgres is the same in this case.

```
With LatestDaily As
(
  select *
  from (
    Select RANK() OVER (Partition By ID ORDER BY Number DESC) as r, *
    From Daily
  ) t
  where t.r = 1
)
Update summary s
   Set Weight = d.Weight, Volume = d.Volume, Density = d.Density
From LatestDaily d 
where s.ID = d.ID;
```

Comment: Postgres needs the `;` at the end, not at the start. The "greatest-n-per-group" problem is typically faster in Postgres when using `distinct on()` instead of a window function. And the `update` syntax with a join is different in Postgres. You should **not** repeat the target table in the `from` clause.

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks!  I wonder if sql server has an equivalent to postgres' distinct on().  That's a neat function.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the syntax errors in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with Daily as (
select d.number, d.Id, d.weight, d.volume, d.density 
From  daily d 
join (select id, max(number) from daily group by ID) d2 on d.number = d2.number
)
update Summary
set weight = d2.weight
, volume = d2.volume
, density = d2.density
from Daily d2
where id = d2.id
and
(weight<> d2.weight OR
volume <> d2.volume OR
density <> d2.density)
)
```

This should ensure that you get the correct newest record per id and only those that need updating.

Comment: Took me a while to get my head around this, but it works well

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Summary SET weight = _weight, volume = _volume, density =_density
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID _ID,weight _weight, volume _volume , density _density
  FROM Details 
  WHERE Number IN (SELECT MAX(Number) FROM Details GROUP BY ID) 
)
A WHERE ID = _ID