# Update Rows Where the following conditions are true

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am attempting to overwrite a field value with the value from another table where a certain condition is true. I have mocked up my code below

Pseudocode:

```
Where an employee has the team Ops in old_data, get their new team from new_data and overwrite the team in old_data
```

My Code:

```
UPDATE old_data -- This has columns Employee, Latest_Team
SET
    Latest_Team = 
           (select new_data.team
            from new_data
            left join old data
            ON old_data.employee = new_data.employee
           )
WHERE old_data.employee = 'Ops'
```

But this is returning the error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I'm not sure where i am going wrong exactly

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database that you are using (2) Sample data and expected results would sure help others understand what you exactly are looking for.

Comment: Your select statement returns more than 1 row.  So latest Team can not be matched  with 1 and only 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the *team* "ops", then your query has several issues:

- You are filtering on the employee, not the team.
- You have a typo in the inner `from` clause.
- You want a correlated subquery.

So, I think you want:

```
UPDATE old_data -- This has columns Employee, Latest_Team
    SET Latest_Team = (select nd.team
                       from new_data nd
                       where old_data.employee = nd.employee
           )
WHERE od.latest_team = 'Ops';
------^  I think this is the filter you describe
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. How would you have done this with a join?

Comment: @andre1990 . . . Many databases don't support `join` syntax in `update`.  And those that do have different syntaxes.  There is no way to answer the question in your comment generically.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this query doesnt return anyting and your code will work

```
select new_data.team, count(*)
            from new_data
            left join old data WHERE old_data.employee = 'Ops'
group by new_data.team
having count(*) > 1
```

If you have more than one team per employee  with Old_data.employee = 'Ops', sql wont know which to choose for that employee for the update

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo in your join - "old data" should be "old_data".

Maybe this can help you: [update columns values with column of another table based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition)

In your example it would be:

```
UPDATE old_data SET
    Latest_Team = (SELECT new_data.team FROM new_data WHERE old_data.employee = new_data.employee LIMIT 1)
    WHERE old_data.employee = 'Ops';
```