# How can I update whole table by selecting from another table in postgress?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have large table with many column and I need to update whole table with select statement. How can I update whole table selecting from another table in postgress?

Comment: To update a table you need an UPDATE query, not a select.
You mean update on table, with SELECT of data from another table ?

Comment: @SonOfHarpy ya I mean to update table by selecting from another table. Edit has been made

Comment: I think you'll find what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

I Think This is what you need :

```
    UPDATE table_a
       SET info = table_b.info
       FROM table_b
       WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id
```

updated according to @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.6) the target table of an UPDATE should **not** be repeated in the FROM clause.