# How to store backward ForeignKey relational COUNT in a table?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table `Post(id,date,title,content,author)`
and a table `Like(id,date,author,post->ForeignKey(Post))`
So I want to add a field 'likes' to the table Post to store the COUNT of likes to have a convenient way to get the COUNT of likes that each post-object has.
Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Create a view instead, will never be inconsistent. Or, at least use triggers to maintain the column.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, [add the column](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) in the post table:

```
ALTER TABLE Post
ADD num_likes int;
```

Then update the `post` table using the `likes` table ([SO question for ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition)):

```
with likes as {
  Select post, Count(1) as num_likes
  FROM Like
  GROUP BY post
}

UPDATE Post 
SET Post.num_likes = likes.num_likes 
FROM Post INNER JOIN likes ON Post.post = likes.post
```

Comment: It looks great. But it works only "by demand" right? I mean it's not automatically populate num_likes when the Like entry creates?

Comment: I don't know how your ETL process works for your database - if you have control over the code that inserts the new Like entries, you could just add this piece to it.

Comment: Yes, actually I use it in my Django project, so I can do it with Django-ORM. I think in that case I can just add the population act of num_likes field of Post to .save() method of the Like model. Or just increment it by 1.

Comment: @ruslanway sounds like a good strategy!