Update multiple column of a SQL table based on another table
I have two tables, TableA & TableB
All tables data are available here: db<>fiddle
TableA as follows:

TableB contains the passed/failed scenario as follows:

I want to updating tableA with data of tableB for particular A_id.
I'm expecting tableA output as:

So, I have write updated query for A_id=2 as follows:
UPDATE  TableA
SET     
    total_count = (SELECT COUNT(A_id) AS total_count 
                FROM TableB WHERE A_id = 2),
    pass_count = (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN(isPassed = 'Y') THEN 1 END) as pass_count 
                FROM TableB WHERE A_id = 2),
    fail_count = (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN(isPassed = 'N') THEN 1 END) as fail_count 
                FROM TableB WHERE A_id = 2)
WHERE   A_id = 2;

And checked the TableA it's updating data properly.

But, above query have 3 different sub-query for each column update. 
So, I want to write updated query as follows:
WITH T0 AS (
    SELECT A_id,
        COUNT(A_id) AS TOTAL_SCENARIOS_COUNT,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN(isPassed = 'Y') THEN 1 END) as PASS_SCENARIOS_COUNT,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN(isPassed = 'N') THEN 1 END) as FAIL_SCENARIOS_COUNT
    from RT_TEST_RUN_SCENARIO
    GROUP BY A_id    
    HAVING A_id = 4779
)
UPDATE  tableA
SET     
    tableA.total_count = t0.total_count,
    tableA.pass_count = t0.pass_count,
    tableA.fail_count = t0.fail_count
FROM tableA INNER JOIN T0
ON tableA.A_id = T0.A_id

But, it's not working. Can you help me how to do that ?
Error is showing as follows:

Is there other way to update TableA ?
N.B: All tables data/query are available here: db<>fiddle

This is my reference query (update table through joining): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition

The aliases in your second update query are wrong.  Is this the actual code you are running, and what is the exact error message?

Have you considered creating a view instead? Will always be up-to-date.

@TimBiegeleisen  Please check the db<>fiddle query: https://dbfiddle.uk/NYNlAwEo
Also update the error message

you can update using join - article heading MySQL UPDATE JOIN Example with LEFT JOIN like UPDATE TableA as A JOIN (SELECT Statement from TableB)  AS B ON A.id = B.id SET a.column = b.column

when I tried same query in oracle-sql server it's not working...
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/b8xorca6gq98jzctmproo6aw8
Have you any suggestion ?

Your current update has multiple problems, the biggest being that you seem to be using SQL Server's update join syntax.  The MySQL update join syntax does the join first, followed by the set.  Also, the aliases you used were inconsistent and had problems.  The following version is working as you expected.
WITH T0 AS (
    SELECT
        A_id,
        COUNT(*) AS total_count,
        SUM(isPassed = 'Y') AS pass_count,
        SUM(isPassed = 'N') AS fail_count
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY A_id
)

UPDATE TableA a
INNER JOIN T0
    ON a.A_id = T0.A_id
SET     
    a.total_count = T0.total_count,
    a.pass_count = T0.pass_count,
    a.fail_count = T0.fail_count;

Demo
By the way, given that the data in TableA is derived from the source TableB, you might want to consider just creating a view based on your T0 cte and then calling it whenever you need to see the data this way.

awesome @TimBiegeleisen, thank you very much

when I tried same query in oracle-sql server it's not working...
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/b8xorca6gq98jzctmproo6aw8
Have you any suggestion ?

@ArtBindu Don't use the MySQL tag when you have a question about Oracle

Alternative answer is:
UPDATE TableA
JOIN (
    SELECT A_id,
        COUNT(*) AS total_count,
        SUM(isPassed = 'Y') AS pass_count,
        SUM(isPassed = 'N') AS fail_count
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY A_id
    -- HAVING A_id = 3
) T0
   ON TableA.A_id = T0.A_id
SET     
    TableA.total_count = T0.total_count,
    TableA.pass_count = T0.pass_count,
    TableA.fail_count = T0.fail_count
WHERE TableA.A_id = T0.A_id;

SELECT * FROM TableA;

https://dbfiddle.uk/2y9O-TkK?highlight=2

Thanks for alternative solution @Dipcoder

Thanks @Dipcoder to helping me oracle-sql server solution
