# impossible to update from a select

Tags: mysql, select

Hi i ve got two tables like this:

```
mysql> describe tb_data_iae;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_dialecte        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| nb_champs          | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                | 
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
mysql> describe tb_dialecte;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id_dialecte       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| nb_champs         | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0          |                | 
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

I try to update first table "nb_champs" field from the same field coming from the second table

```
mysql> update tb_data_iae 
       set nb_champs=tb_dialecte.nbchamps  
      from tb_dialecte 
      where tb_dialecte.id_dialecte = tb_data_iae.id_dialecte;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from tb_dialecte where tb_dialecte.id_dialecte = tb_data_iae.id_dialecte' at line 1

I don't know how to debug this, as I try many queries but no ones works and the error message is pretty much the same everytime as the one above...

Thx for help !

Comment: Are you simply trying to do a 1 time clone or how will this be used?

Comment: yes I will use this query one time, just to reorganize data in the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update tb_data_iae set nb_champs=(SELECT tb_dialecte.nbchamps 
from tb_dialecte 
where tb_dialecte.id_dialecte = tb_data_iae.id_dialecte);
```

Though I'd ask why store the same values in two tables?

Comment: It s because I made a migration of store data from one table to another, to sort out information more clearly in the database

Comment: there s something I don t understand in this query, how do the update know which id_dialecte as to be set with the nb_champs value ?

Comment: It looks up the record in tb_dialecte from the id you give it in the where statement. It's the same way a JOIN works in a select statement

Answer (score 1):

When I look in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html, it looks like update...from is not allowed.

```
update tb_data_iae,tb_dialecte 
set tb_data_iae.nb_champs=tb_dialecte.nbchamps 
where nb_dialecte.id_dialecte = tb_data_iae.id_dialecte;
```

Comment: what about this thread, it s the one i get inspired to write my query but for me it s not working ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Comment: that question was for Microsoft SQL Server, it won't work in MySql I think

Comment: god dammit, note for myself read more carefully the associated tags, thx !