# SQL Server 2008: update date from row in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've seen this question a lot, but I can't seem to get my SQL to work so I'm hoping someone can help. 
I've confirmed that this code will work in Access, but it isn't working with SQL Server 2008.

```
UPDATE shop_orders AS t1, shop_orders AS t2 
SET t1.shipstreet1 = t2.shipstreet1,
    t1.shipstreet2 = t2.shipstreet2, 
    t1.shipcity = t2.shipcity, 
    t1.shipregionstate = t2.shipregionstate
WHERE t1.orderid=3292 
  AND t2.orderid=3641;
```

Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server's T-SQL, you cannot have multiple tables in the `UPDATE` clause, nor can you give that table a table alias.

You need to use:

```
UPDATE shop_orders 
FROM shop_orders AS t2 
SET shipstreet1 = t2.shipstreet1,
    shipstreet2 = t2.shipstreet2, 
    shipcity = t2.shipcity, 
    shipregionstate = t2.shipregionstate
WHERE shop_orders.orderid = 3292 
  AND t2.orderid = 3641;
```

Comment: You can give the table an alias if you include it in the `FROM` clause (and in fact, kind of need to if you're doing a self join in the `FROM`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: correct - but not really needed here, that's why I skipped that

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for Update From is different for SQL server, the same query will not work in both.

See:
[SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

For more information on Update From syntax.