# sql server update query fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Itemmaster` table and want to update the price from the `itemmaster` table into DailySales table.

```
ItemMaster (ItemName, Price)

DailySales (Date, ItemName, Price)
```

My query is:

```
update DailySales a 
set Price = (select b.price 
             from DailySales a, Itemmaster b where a.itemname = b.itemname)
```

The above query fails. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Qinnovator: please **update** your original question with the error message by **editing it** - don't post longer text here in comments! Really hard to read....

Comment: this link is useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tell us much about **how** it fails (error message or anything) - but I believe this statement ought to work:

```
UPDATE ds
SET ds.Price = im.Price
FROM dbo.DailySales ds
INNER JOIN dbo.Itemmaster im ON im.itemname = ds.itemname
```

Points to remember:

- put your table name you want to update into the `FROM` clause and give it a **meaningful** table alias (not just `a` or `b`) - use that table alias in the `UPDATE` statement
- use `INNER JOIN` (instead of "embedded" JOIN by just having table after table, comma-separated) to spell out your JOIN intention and your JOIN conditions

Comment: Thanks for informing me about the alias name to be used

Answer (score 1):

I assume your query fail because you are trying to assign result set (returned by SELECT) to a single column value. You need to use `INNER JOIN` to specify how each single row from ItemMaster correspond to a row from DailySales table, then you would be able to assign a Price value for the appropriate entries:

```
UPDATE DailySales
  SET ds.Price = im.Price
FROM DailySales ds
INNER JOIN ItemMaster im ON ds.ItemName = im.ItemName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update  a
set     Price = b.Price
from    DailySales a
        join ItemMaster b on a.ItemName = b.ItemName
```

Comment: Agree with marc_s that using `a` and `b` isn't particularly useful, but I thought it might help the OP understand it better.