# I am trying to update only certain rows in a table, but the others get NULL'd out

Tags: database, sqlite, null, sql-update

I am trying to run a simple Update query on a certain set of rows in my sqlite db. It works, but it NULLs out all the other rows. Here is the query:

`update table1 set col5 =(select col5 from table2 where table2.id = table1.id)`

I know this is super easy, but I can't figure out what is going on. Can't I only update certain rows, and leave the rest alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same columns you are updating to relate the two tables. You should use a **primary or secondary key** to relate the two tables.

See this very similar question and its answer: [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: In your original question, that is. The link is still relevant though.

Comment: @oofgwen add this to the query: `where exists (select * from table2 where table2.id = table1.id)` to avoid setting NULL values on non matching rows.

Comment: That last part was it!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
update table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
set table1.col5 = table2.col5
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, didn't realise it was sqlite.  sqlite doesn't support joins in the update clause.
My best guess is you could do the following:

```
update table1 set col5 = (select col5 from table2 where table2.id = table1.id)
where id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: Has anyone actually tried or reasoned about this? Its semantics are: set a.x = b.x where a.x = b.x. It will result in an updated timestamp at best.

Comment: So I tried the query, and my simple sqlite browser throws an error thanks to the inner keyword...I know I've done this type of thing before, I just can't remember how to do it.

Comment: I realised it was doing nothing, I figured he was just using placeholders for the column names...

Comment: I'm so sorry guys, I didn't have it down right. I updated it with the correct values. I can't get the join to work though...I really would like to get to the bottom of this. Thanks!