# Wrting Sql insert into statement using select statement

Tags: sql, insert

I want to insert some values to a table (item1) from a table (item2) and date which is not in that item2 table.

How do I write a SQL insert into statement using the select statement to achieve that?

eg :

```
INSERT into item1(date, name, qty) 
values(datevalue, select col1, col2 from item2);
```

This isn't working. What should I do to fix it?

```
insert into daily_stock(date, product_id, name, weight, qty, free_issues, sales_price, 
                        purchased_price, category, last_purchased_date) 

     select 
        **'"+today+"'**,
        productId, name, weight, newQty, freeIssues, NewSalesPrice,
        NewPurchasePrice, category, datePurchased 
     from product
```

I'm using java and today is a string variable , still data is not inserting , whats wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're almost there: just use the `SELECT` variation for `INSERT` instread of `VALUES`, and include your data there as a constant:

```
insert into item1(date,name,qty) 
select <datevalue>, col1, col2 from item2;
```

If your date comes from another table, you can do this:

```
 insert into item1(date,name,qty) 
 select d.dcol1, i2.col1, i2.col2 
 from item2 i2 inner join table_containing_date_col d
 on <some join criteria>
```

**EDIT:** you have to ensure that the data types match i.e. your  has to be parsable to a date if you are savign it to a date field (which you are, hopefully!). You don't give details of your database but it would be something like this for SQL Server

```
cast('your date in yyyymmdd format' as datetime)
```

(`yyyymmdd` always works as it is recognisable ISO format)

or better still [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

For MySql you have [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), for Oracle [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) etc.etc.

Comment: funny... I never *ever* code the keyword `inner`, since it's the default join type in every database and everyone knows that.

Answer (score 2):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO item1 (date, name, qty) 
SELECT 'value here' as datevalue, col1, col2 
FROM   item2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a specific SQL server/type you are using, in T-SQL this can be done like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT '29/01/2012', T2.Column1, T2.Column2 FROM Table2 T2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

```
INSERT into ITEM1 (date, name, qty) 
values (datevalue, (SELECT col1, col2 FROM item2));
```