# MySql Update a table with data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables that are identical in structure. `Table1` holds moderated data, `table2` holds the rest.

**Table 1**

```
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "id" | "name" | "description" | "type" | "country" |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "1"  | "a"    | "x"           | "1"    | "US"      |
| "2"  | "b"    | "x"           | "1"    | "UK"      |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "id" |  "name"   |  "description"  | "type" | "country" | "status" |
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "1"  | "Title 1" | "Description 1" | "1"    | "US"      | "0"      |
| "2"  | "Title 2" | "Description 2" | "10"   | "UK"      | "0"      |
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I run the below sql in order to update `table 1` with data from `table 2`, and it works well. The only problem is, I need to specify the `id` in both places. If I were to specify it only in one place, where would it go?

```
UPDATE table1 dest, 
       (SELECT name, 
               description 
        FROM   table2 
        WHERE  id = 1) src 
SET    dest.name = src.name, 
       dest.description = src.description 
WHERE  dest.id = 1;
```

The way this thing goes is:

```
UPDATE table1 SET name AND description =
(
   SELECT name, description from table2
   WHERE id=1 AND country=us and type=10
) WHERE id=idfromselect AND country=countryfromselect AND type=typefromselect
```

I can't figure out where to put the `id` and `remaining conditions`. Can you help?

Comment: You can use a join condition 
see this link it might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 1):

Do it as a join, put the id in the join condition and just check the id in the WHERE clause.

Something like this:-

```
UPDATE table1 dest INNER JOIN table2 src ON dest.id = src=id
SET dest.name = src.name, dest.description = src.description 
WHERE dest.id=1 ;
```

Any other restrictions can just be added to the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an [**`INNER JOIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query to update your table1 basing on data from table2 and put your condition in `WHERE` clauses

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.name = b.name,
a.description = b.description
WHERE a.id=1;
```