# Updating a table with data from another table

Tags: sql

So I have TABLE_ONE with two columns...ID and EXPIRE_DATE

and TABLE_TWO with the same two columns except the EXPIRE_DATE has a dummy value and needs to be populated from the first table.

I need to grab the most recent EXPIRE_DATE (latest date not last added) for a given ID from TABLE_ONE and populate all occurences of that ID in TABLE_TWO with that EXPIRE_DATE.

I guess it's clear that ID is not the PK in either table. It recurs.

How would I write this UPDATE of TABLE_TWO?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match?rq=1

Comment: You should always tell what database your are using, and an actual sample is welcome too (although in this case not really necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
update table2
set expire_date = expdate
from table2 join 
(select id, max(expire_date) expdate
from table1
where whatever
group by id ) temp on table2.id = temp.id
where whatever
```

Note that your two where clauses should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `set` clause:

```
update table_two
    set expire_date = (select max(t1.expire_date) from table_one t1 where t1.id = table_two.id);
```

This is standard SQL syntax and should work in all (or almost all databases).  Some databases allow joins in the `update` clause, but not all.  Even among the ones that do, the syntax varies.