# syntax error in update with inner join query mysql

Tags: mysql

#### My Query :

```
UPDATE i SET i.CurStock = i.CurStock-g.Qty  
    FROM inv_inventarymaster AS i INNER JOIN inv_goodsissue AS g  
    ON  i.ItemName = g.ItemName WHERE g.DATE='2014-03-20';
```

#### Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspond
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near    'FROM
>   inv_inventarymaster as i INNER JOIN inv_goodsissue as g ON ' at line 1

Kindly help me getting the right syntax.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match/224740#224740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...Not Tested but as MYsql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE inv_inventarymaster AS i INNER JOIN inv_goodsissue AS g SET 
i.CurStock = i.CurStock-g.Qty 
WHERE i.ItemName = g.ItemName and g.DATE='2014-03-20';
```

Comment: @user3092228 : dont forget to mark accepted if it helped...i am upvoting on your behalf!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

its not a right thing to use `FROM` in Mysql `UPDATE` query.

You can use the query like this

```
UPDATE inv_inventarymaster AS i 
INNER JOIN inv_goodsissue AS g  ON i.ItemName = g.ItemName 
SET i.CurStock = i.CurStock-g.Qty  
WHERE g.DATE='2014-03-20';
```