# Update a table from another table on multiple columns in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Oracle 11g SQL & both tables have the same column definitions:

```
VARCHAR2(11)
NUMBER
DATE
DATE
```

I tried to find a solution to this problem, and this is what I ended up with, which fails:

```
update jjjTable
set [fourthCol] = B.[fourthOtherCol]
from jjjTable, otherTable B
where jjjTable.[firstCol] = B.[firstOtherCol]
and jjjTable.[secondCol] = B.[secondOtherCol]
and jjjTable.[thirdCol] = B.[thirdOtherCol]
```

I'm under the impression that I need to have the from in this was based on this article:

[SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match/224740#224740) and the edited response from Shivkant

I'm under the impression that I may need to use a join based on this article:

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server/2334741#2334741) and the response from Robin Day

but as I understand it, joins are only on one column match per row. I'm interested in matching on 3 elements, and I'm not finding a clear path for solution.

Any direction would be well received.

Comment: Perhaps this related question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: I greatly appreciate the suggestion. I'll see if I can adapt some of the code to work with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up needing to do as a solution:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR j_CUR IS

SELECT A.[fourthCol]
FROM JJJtable A, otherTable B
WHERE A.[firstCol] = B.[firstOtherCol]
and A.[secondCol] = B.[secondOtherCol]
and A.[thirdCol] = B.[thirdOtherCol]

FOR UPDATE OF B.[fourthOtherCol];
SOME_DATE DATE;

BEGIN
FOR IDX IN j_CUR LOOP
SOME_DATE :=(IDX.[fourthCol]);
UPDATE otherTable
SET [fourthOtherCol] = SOME_DATE
WHERE CURRENT OF j_CUR;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Thank you for your efforts and guidance.

Comment: I'd love to find a more elegant solution, but this one worked.

Comment: Edited to reflect original Column nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

This is the close best I was able to get it to work on my similar use case. Try this out.

```sql
update jjjTable
SET jjjTable.[fourthCol] = (SELECT distint otherTable.fourthOtherCol from otherTable 
                            WHERE otherTable.firstOtherCol = jjjTable.firstCol and 
                                otherTable.secondOtherCol = jjjTable.secondCol and 
                                otherTable.thirdOtherCol = jjjTable.thirdCol)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT distint otherTable.fourthOtherCol from otherTable 
                            WHERE otherTable.firstOtherCol = jjjTable.firstCol and 
                                otherTable.secondOtherCol = jjjTable.secondCol and 
                                otherTable.thirdOtherCol = jjjTable.thirdCol);
```