# Update DB Table based on another temp Table data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a temp table in which I'm inserting data. In temp table data is ok and I want to update another table with temp table data. I'm new to SQL
My Query is:

```
update result_table set result_table.a = temp.a, 
                        result_table.b = temp.b 
from temp where temp.a= 1
```

I'm deleting the data in temp table and inserting data again in temp table and updating the result table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLServer you tagged both?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLServer? They are different

Comment: I'm using SQLServer and I want to use query in my code

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: @Ninjapig, thanks for your reply.But it's not working on my issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE B
[INSERT WHERE CONDITIONS HERE]
```

Just make sure that the table structure of both tables are the same.