# To update the table1 considering data of table2

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Table1 
columns: id, name

Table2
columns: id, status.

How to make request that **update Table1.name** for Table1.id = 'some_id' if Table2.id = Table1.id and Table2.status = 'some_status' ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that in a separate table? Does it work for you to have a single table with "id, name, status" columns?

Comment: The structure of tables can't be changed.

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match).

Comment: What did you try so far? And, Update what in table1? The matching ID itself?

Comment: Watch a question: need to update Table1.name field. + i tried INNER JOIN in UPDATE, but it's not work in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Table1 set Table1.name = 'XXX'
where Table1.id = 'some_id' 
  and exists (select 1 from Table2 where Table2.id = Table1.id and Table2.status = 'some_status');
```

> The EXISTS keyword tests for the existence of any rows in a subquery.
>   If no rows are found, the answer is FALSE. Otherwise, the subquery
>   returns TRUE. NOT EXISTS reverses the results.
>
> Note that the entire subquery is executed, even though EXISTS need
>   only know whether or not the subquery returns any rows — so beware
>   using EXISTS with subqueries that return large numbers of rows.
>
> It’s worth noting that this sort of query is sometimes referred to as
>   a “semijoin”. A semijoin is a SELECT statement that uses the EXISTS
>   keyword to compare rows in a table with rows in another table.

In addition to that it's a **correlated query** which is executing for each row of Table1.

EXISTS may replace IN in many cases and often is more beneficial than IN.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: That is exact that is necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
update table1
set table1.name = 'newName'
FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.status = 1enter code here
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/00d52cb2-829a-4749-aa4c-b9552405345e/update-com-inner-join