# Sql update a table based on the values of a join from another table

Tags: mysql

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match) this should work, but it isn't working correctly:

```
UPDATE `cms_download` 
SET folder_id = '230'
FROM `cms_download` file
LEFT JOIN `cms_download_folder` folder
ON file.folder_id = folder.folder_id
WHERE file.client_id = '69'
AND folder.folder_id = NULL
```

What I have is a files table (cms_download) which contains a column that refers to the folder that contains this file (cms_download_folder). And what I'm trying to do is set all the files that do not have a folder assigned to them to a particular folder. I can know that by left or right joining in the two tables together on the folder id, and where the entry doesn't exist in the (cms_download_folder) table against the entry in (cms_download) table I would change the folder_id in the (cms_download) table so that it would refer to an entry that exists.

I hope I'm making sense.

Thanks to Gordon, I got to the correct query which is:

```
UPDATE  `cms_download` file 
LEFT JOIN  `cms_download_folder` folder 
ON file.folder_id = folder.folder_id 
SET file.folder_id =  '230' 
WHERE file.client_id =  '69' 
AND folder.folder_id = NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using SQL Server syntax but your post is tagged MySQL.  The `join` goes before the `set` in MySQL:

```
UPDATE `cms_download` file LEFT JOIN
       `cms_download_folder` folder
        ON file.folder_id = folder.folder_id
    SET folder_id = '230'
WHERE file.client_id = '69' AND folder.folder_id = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, however in that case I wouldn't need the `FROM cms_download file`. I will write the final query in my question because I'm unable to properly format it here.

Comment: @NaguibIhab . . . Correct.  That was a copy-and-paste error.