# Joining two table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

In this Table1 and Table2 (AttendanceDate,EmployeeCode) are PRIMARY Key..
How can we replace table1 value with table2 where ever AttendanceDate and EmployeeCode will match..

Like Result table..

Comment: Use an `outer join` with `coalesce`... Try something and let us know where you're having troubles.

Comment: join two tables and use `case` when `ID` match

Comment: Outer join with coalesce!

Comment: I think your looking for an update statement.  Example found in a prior answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this untested query:

```
select t1.AttendanceDate, t1.EmployeeCode, case when t2.duration is null then t1.duration else t2.duration end 
from table1 t1 left outer join table t2 on t1.AttendanceDate= t2.AttendanceDate and  t1.EmployeeCode =  t2.EmployeeCode
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
SELECT Table1.AtendanceDate, Table1.EmployeeCode,
    CASE WHEN Table2.Duration IS NOT NULL THEN Table2.Duration ELSE Table1.Duration END AS Duration
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AtendanceDate = Table2.AtendanceDate 
    AND Table1.EmployeeCOde = Table2.EmployeeCode
```

Comment: Syntax error. And you can't mix datatypes in a COALESCE like that.

Comment: That's what I get for not proofreading.  I started with a COALESCE and then changed changed my mind.