# postgreSQL: use JOIN and UPDATE to update one table with data from another

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to do something that I'm assuming is very simple, but it has me stumped.

I have a furniture table which includes a text column called "category" (beds, chairs, desks etc) and a categories table which pairs each of these categories, in a column called categoryname, to a categoryID (this was added at the request of a team member, to facilitate searching).

I want to populate a column in the furniture table with these categoryIDs, based on whether there's a match between the category column in the furniture table and the categoryname column in the categories table.

After searching around this site and elsewhere I decided to try this:

```
UPDATE furniture
SET categoryid = categories.categoryid
FROM categories
WHERE categories.categoryname = furniture.category
```

Which runs, but nothing happens.

I'm assuming it's because that WHERE statement isn't enough to get across what I'm trying to do and I need some kind of JOIN statement to explicitly link the categoryname column in the categories table with the category column in the furniture table, but how I do incorporate this? My best guess based on what worked for others was something like this:

```
UPDATE furniture
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.categoryname = furniture.category
SET furniture.categoryid = categories.categoryid
WHERE categories.categoryname = furniture.category
```

But it's just giving me syntax errors.

(I've checked to make sure the categoryname and category columns match in terms of spelling etc)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match?rq=1

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server, or Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
UPDATE f
SET 
    categoryid = c.categoryid
from furniture f
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.categoryname = f.category
```

Could you copy again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working- relation "f" does not exist, if I get rid of the aliases it tells me that table name furniture has been specified more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You should respect this syntax :

```
UPDATE furniture
SET furniture.categoryid = categories.categoryid
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.categoryname = furniture.category
WHERE categories.categoryname = furniture.category
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this- "table name "furniture" specified more than once"