# Update row in SQL Server based on reference from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables, one named issue and the other named activ in SQL Server 2008. I am deleting a column in issue, but before I do so, I want to find the corresponding column in activ, and update a field. I'm just not sure how to reference activ.

```
issue
iissueid, iactivid, ...
```

---

```
activ
iactivid, rtfnotes, ...
```

---

```
UPDATE activ 
    SET activ.rtfnotes = NULL   
FROM issue
    JOIN activ.iactivid = issue.iactivid
WHERE issue.iissueid = @tID

DELETE issue WHERE iissueid = @tID
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong. I'm pretty sure I am almost there.

Comment: In your UPDATE you have `SET active.rtfnotes = NULL` where everywhere else its `activ`. That could be the problem unless it is just a typo here.

Comment: @Walker - It was just a typo here, which I fixed. Thank you for making me aware of it.

Comment: "JOIN activ.iactivid = issue.iactivid" is not valid syntax.   You JOIN a table/view ON a condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: @TabAlleman - That was it. Stupid mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.rtfnotes = NULL   
FROM activ a
    JOIN issue i ON a.iactivid = i.iactivid AND i.iissueid = @tID

DELETE issue WHERE iissueid = @tID
```