# select only a few columns from a large table in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have to join 2 tables on a key (say XYZ). I have to update one single column in table A using a coalesce function. Coalesce(a.status_cd, b.status_cd).

TABLE A:
contains some 100 columns. KEY Columns ABC.

TABLE B: 
Contains just 2 columns. KEY Column ABC and status_cd

TABLE A, which I use in this left join query is having more than 100 columns. Is there a way to use a.* followed by this coalesce function in my PROC SQL without creating a new column from the PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE AS ... step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of dataset options to make it so you can use wildcards in the select statement.  Note that the order of the columns could change doing this.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
    select a.*
         , coalesce(a.old_status,b.status_cd) as status_cd
    from tableA(rename=(status_cd=old_status)) a
    left join tableB b
      on a.abc = b.abc
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Will this replace the whole table or will it just update the relevant values?

Comment: Hi Tom, the status_cd column is already present in the table (column name is not old_status) referred with alias 'a'. I think my query will fail . I will make the changes, test it and will confirm though.

Comment: That is what the RENAME= dataset option does. It renames the variable on the way in.  So if the name was STATUS_CD then the rename option changes the name to OLD_STATUS.

Comment: Thank you Tom. It worked. I thought it will through error as both the OLD_STATUS and NEW_STATUS column names are same. But still it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: user667489 - It replaces the whole table, but I need not give all the columns and it became really simple. Thank you for your answers. They gave a great insight into the DATA step and update table syntax

Comment: It can be used to replace the whole table or create a new table.  You normally do not use SAS to update data in place.  You would normally do that in your data collection tool.

Comment: Tom, will it work "from tableA(rename=(status_cd=status_cd)) a" .. I tried it, but I am able to pull the a.status_cd into status_cd created in "want" all the time. Even when a.status_cd is null and b.status_cd is present I am getting only a.status_cd which is null. coalesce function has no effect on this scenario.

Comment: Renaming A to A does nothing.  If you try to select two columns with the same name then PROC SQL will only save the first one.  So if you leave the name as STATUS_CD and then try to create another variable that is also named STATUS_CD in the same output dataset the second does not make it into the output dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a fairly simple way of doing this in `proc sql` after working through several more complex approaches:

```
proc sql noprint;
  update master a
  set status_cd= coalesce(status_cd,
                           (select status_cd
                            from transaction b
                            where a.key= b.key))
  where exists (select 1
                from transaction b
                where a.ABC = b.ABC);
quit;
```

This will update just the one column you're interested in and will only update it for rows with key values that match in the transaction dataset.

**Earlier attempts:**

The most obvious bit of more general SQL syntax would seem to be the `update...set...from...where` pattern as used in the top few answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match). However, this syntax is not currently supported - the documentation for the [SQL update statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002294530.htm) only allows for a `where` clause, not a `from` clause.

If you are running a pass-through query to another database that does support this syntax, it might still be a viable option.

Alternatively, there is a way to do this within SAS via a data step, provided that the master dataset is indexed on your key variable:

```
/*Create indexed master dataset with some missing values*/
data master(index = (name));
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_ <= 5 then call missing(weight);
run;

/*Create transaction dataset with some missing values*/
data transaction;
  set sashelp.class(obs = 10 keep = name weight);
  if _n_ > 5 then call missing(weight);
run;

data master;
  set transaction;
  t_weight = weight;
  modify master key = name;
  if _IORC_ = 0 then do;
      weight = coalesce(weight, t_weight);
      replace;
  end;
  /*Suppress log messages if there are key values in transaction but not master*/  
  else _ERROR_ = 0; 
run;
```

A standard warning relating to the the `modify` statement: if this data step is interrupted then the master dataset may be irreparably damaged, so make sure you have a backup first.

In this case I've assumed that the key variable is unique - a slightly more complex data step is needed if it isn't.

Another way to work around the lack of a `from` clause in the `proc sql` `update` statement would be to set up a format merge, e.g.

```
data v_format_def /view = v_format_def;
    set transaction(rename = (name = start weight = label));
    retain fmtname 'key' type 'i';
    end = start;
run;

proc format cntlin = v_format_def; run;

proc sql noprint;
    update master 
        set weight = coalesce(weight,input(name,key.))
        where master.name in (select name from transaction);
run;
```

In this scenario I've used `type = 'i'` in the format definition to create a numeric informat, which proc sql uses convert the character variable `name` to the numeric variable `weight`. Depending on whether your `key` and `status_cd` columns are character or numeric you may need to do this slightly differently.

This approach effectively loads the entire transaction dataset into memory when using the format, which might be a problem if you have a very large transaction dataset. The data step approach should hardly use any memory as it only has to load 1 row at a time.