# Move data between tables

Tags: liquibase

I'm currently using Liquibase in a small project of mine, which works pretty fine.
But right now i'm facing a problem. My ChangeLog works as expected in my testenv but fails on my productiv one. This happens because my prod-tables contain a few rows of data.

I know there is an UPDATE-Command in liquibase, but im not sure how to use it correctly.

What i want to archive is to move a column from table B to table A without losing its data. Table B contains a foreignkey of table A. A normal SQL-Statement would look smth like `update A set A.x = (select B.x from B where B.id = A.id)`

It would be nice if someone could give me a example of such an update-changeset.

Thx!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to use a [`<sql>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) tag and write the `update` statement into that tag. I find the [`<update>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html) _tag_ pretty cumbersome to use.

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. It's still interesting for me to see how it would work with a `<update>` tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may look like

```
<changeSet ...>
    <update tableName="TABLE_A">
            <column name="x" valueComputed="(select b.x from TABLE_B b where b.id=id)"/>
    </update>
</changeset>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want from more than one table you should have a `where` clause or you will end up overriding the previous update operation to nulls,

in other words you will have problem of `xTable.newColumn` being set to `null` for rows of `xTable` that had `no matching` key in `yTable`

and don't worry the where clause will solve this problem, simply add this where clause:

```
xTable.itsId =(the same select statement in valueComputed but select Id instead)
```

here is a real example

```
<changeSet id="0.0.6.1" author="bmomani">
 .....
    <update tableName="change">
        <column name="WIDGET_ID" valueComputed="(SELECT insert_widget.WIDGET_ID FROM insert_widget WHERE change.ID = insert_widget.ID)"/>
        <where>change.id = (SELECT insert_widget.ID FROM insert_widget WHERE change.ID = insert_widget.ID)</where>
    </update>

    <update tableName="change">
        <column name="WIDGET_ID" valueComputed="(SELECT remove_widget.WIDGET_ID FROM remove_widget WHERE change.ID = remove_widget.ID)">
        </column>
        <where>change.id = (SELECT remove_widget.ID FROM remove_widget WHERE change.ID = remove_widget.ID)</where>
    </update>
    <comment>note that we can do this in one update statement if we used union</comment>

    <comment> optional to drop column</comment>
    <!--<dropColumn tableName="insert_widget" columnName="widget_id"/>-->
    <!--<dropColumn tableName="remove_widget" columnName="widget_id"/>-->
</changeSet>
```

in this snippet, I wanted to move `widget_id` column from `insert_widget` table to `change` table, but change table already has data, so I have to use update statement

thanks to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/224807/4251431  it helped me figure out the query