# MYSQL - UPDATE multiple rows from another table

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have 2 tables. one from yesterday (300k rows) and another one from today with the same count of rows but the data changes in some columns.

Those two tables have around 120 columns.

How can i update only the changes.
I have tried using delete :

```
   delete from tableA
   where id in (select id from tableB)
```

But it too slow.
Also tried

```
   update tableA inner join tableB
   on tableA.id=TableB.id
```

And it didn't worked.

[image]

Comment: What didn't work when you tried tableA inner join tableB on tableA.id=TableB.id ?

Comment: I was trying  to to find the inner and the  update - didn't worked. received error 1064 - something wrong with the syntax

Comment: well then you have to list the column you want to update, like in Code-Monk's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set the values in your update query to get the changes.

Example:

```
update tableA inner join tableB on tableA.id=TableB.id
set tableA.col1=TableB.col1,
    tableA.col2=TableB.col2,
    tableA.col3=TableB.col3;
```

and also you can add more conditions in `where` clause to make query run on filtered records.

Comment: i have in both tables around   120 columns . is there a way to do this all together?

Comment: yeah..but you have set only those columns want to get changes. If you want to update all column values, you can try other tools like `Excel` to prepare query .

Comment: If you get an error like "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect." you can add `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;`
[more info...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66529407/2587338)

Answer (score 0):

delete from tableA
   where id in (select id from tableB)

Instead of above query try this:-

```
Delete tableA from tableA left Join tableB ON  tableA.id = tableB.id where tableB.id IS NOT NULL;
```