# Grab value from another table via foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my SQL Server database:

```
Person

ID Lastname  Age
1  Jones     46
2  Smith     37

Employee

ID(FK) Firstname Surname
1      Bob       [empty string]
2      Janet     [empty string]
```

I want to combine Employee as follows. (I will then be removing the Lastname from person, but let's not worry about that for now.)

```
Employee 
ID (FK)   Firstname  Surname
1         Bob        Jones
2         Janet      Smith
```

How can I do that?

Comment: SQL newbie, picking up a project, sorry if it's an obvious question.

Comment: This is the question I really wanted to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you should try this query, by this way you will have your desired result based on both tables.

```
Select E.ID, E.FirstName P.Lastname As Surname From Person P
Inner join Employee E ON p.ID = E.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select E.ID, E.Firstname, P.Lastname as Surname from Employee E 
inner join Person P on P.ID=E.ID
```