# PSQL not updating uniquely but copying value onto all entries---Foreign Key update

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

This is looking for solutions in PSQL or PGAdmin III:

I have set up the SQL command as follows as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match):

```
UPDATE members
SET pers_id=P.pers_id
--SELECT *
FROM persons P
INNER JOIN members M
ON M.full_name=P.full_name
```

However it is not updating the column `pers_id` with the individual value instead it is copying the data point from the first query onto all entries.

It should be noted that `pers_id` is a foreign key in the members table.

Comment: What does `SELECT P.pers_id, P.full_name FROM persons P INNER JOIN members M ON M.full_name = P.full_name` show you?

Comment: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*". The linked question is for SQL Server which uses a different syntax.

Comment: The above query updated with all the same number. 754, the id from the first entry as if it started with `SELECT * FROM persons p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE members
SET pers_id=persons.pers_id
FROM persons
WHERE members.full_name = persons.full_name
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought that the table.column syntax didn't work in psql