# update data from one table to another using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 2 tables `EmployeeData` and `employeePersonalData`.

I have common column `emailId`.

Now I want copy all the `emailId` from `employeeData` to `employeePersonalData`
how can I do?

Comment: how are the two tables joined together. When you say copy do you want to update the target column or you want to insert a new row?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Do you want to only copy the ID and leave all other columns blank?  Is this an update or an insert?

Comment: yes i want to copy only the mailid column. And the mailid column in employeePersonalData already have data ,i want to update the whole data with employeeData table

Answer (score 1):

you can visit [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

It provides us two approach.

Before that please check you should be having one more common column similar to `EmployeeId` in both the tables.

so then you can use either of below approach -

1) using `UPDATE FROM` with a `JOIN` will help

```
Update employeePersonalData 
   set employeePersonalData.emailId =employeeData.emailId 
  from employeePersonalData  inner join employeeData b 
    on employeePersonalData.emploeeId =employeeData.employeeId
```

2) Using `merge`

```
MERGE INTO employeePersonalData
   USING employeeData
      ON employeePersonalData.emailId =employeeData.emailId 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET employeePersonalData.emailId =employeeData.emailId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update a set a.emailId =b.emailId  from employeePersonalData a inner join 
employeeData b on  a.emailId =b.emailId

Comment: join on a.emailId = b.emailId but then set a.emailId = b.emailId ?

Comment: that will update  employeeData (emailid) to employeePersonalData (emailid )

Comment: you have any other common column except emailid?

Comment: yes i have..., actually employeePersonalData table contain all column in employeeData

Comment: ok fine, you try to join the table any Id column  instead of emailid