# How to write a SQL query to update a table based of a result in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 different tables in my database and can't find any reference on how to use a result to update a part of a table.

Here is my scenario

Table: **MenuItems**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  Name        ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ test         ║
║  2 ║ test2        ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Table: **MenuItemPrices**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  Price       ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ 3.50         ║
║  2 ║ 4.50         ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Say I want to update test2 price to 5.00, what would be the query I need?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry @juergend its for microsoft sql server

Comment: No code examples? Seems like a homework problem...

Comment: @Squirrel answer should work then

Comment: @openwonk yep it workerd perfectly.

Comment: Cant find any reference? Had you typed your question into google, you would have found more than a few [including this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: @GaryWalker I did google it and I did find that problem, but I felt that question did not sufficiently explain what I was attemtping to acheive and if you see the answers I got from this question were sufficiently different from that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE p
SET    Price = 5.00
FROM   MenuItems i
INNER JOIN MenuItemPrice p ON i.id = p.id
WHERE  i.Name = 'test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE p
SET Price = 5.00
FROM   
    MenuItems i,
    MenuItemPrice p 
WHERE 
    i.id = p.id AND
    i.Name = 'test2'
```