# Oracle SQL Update Table Based on Matching ID

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update, insert-update

I am attempting to update the `GPID` field of table `DIM_TRADING_ACCOUNTS` based on the `GPID` field of `MASTER_CUSTOMER` where the `MCUST_CODE` in `MASTER_CUSTOMER` is equal to the `TRADING_CODE` of `DIM_TRADING_ACCOUNTS` and no matter what I try, I get what basically amounts to an syntax error each time.

I have been taking guidance from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match). The four attempts I have made so far are below along with errors. Can someone please help me get the proper syntax for oracle SQL that works?

*Note: I used upper on `mcust_code` because the `trading_code` field is all upper-case*

**Attempt 1** *(error is: SQL command not properly ended)*

```
UPDATE dim_trading_accounts dta
  SET dta.gpid = mc.gpid
FROM master_customer mc
WHERE UPPER(mc.mcust_code) = dta.trading_code;
```

**Attempt 2** *(error is: missing "SET" keyword)*

```
UPDATE 
  dim_trading_accounts dta, master_customer mc
SET
  dta.gpid = mc.gpid
WHERE
  upper(mc.mcust_code) = dta.trading_code;
```

**Attempt 3** *(this one returns error: single-row subquery returns more than one row)*

```
UPDATE dim_trading_accounts dta
SET dta.gpid = (SELECT mc.gpid
                FROM master_customer mc
                WHERE dta.trading_code = upper(mc.mcust_code))
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM master_customer mc
              WHERE dta.trading_code = upper(mc.mcust_code));
```

**Attempt 4** *(error is: missing "ON" keyword)*

```
MERGE INTO dim_trading_accounts
  USING master_customer
    ON dim_trading_accounts.trading_code = upper(master_customer.mcust_code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET dim_trading_accounts.gpid = master_customer.gpid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `max` or `min` in the sub-query to avoid `single-row subquery returns more than one row` error.

```
UPDATE 
  dim_trading_accounts dta
SET
  dta.gpid = (SELECT MAX(gpid) 
              FROM master_customer 
              WHERE upper(mcust_code) = dta.trading_code);
```

To see why the error comes up, use a `select` and check the results for `gpid` and `tradingcode` combination.

```
 SELECT mc.gpid, dta.trading_code
 FROM master_customer mc
 JOIN dim_trading_accounts dta ON upper(mc.mcust_code) = dta.trading_code
```

If you see duplicate rows from the `select` above, you can be sure to use `max` or `min` in the `update`.

Comment: yes, I discovered this and the interesting thing is that i filtered out the `mccust_code` with multiple `gpid` and i still get the error. *(I filtered them out because I want to update the rest and check the multiple ones manually)*

Comment: nevermind, I found the other two offenders that I missed by accident :)  ... thanks for the help :) I think i got it straight now :) ... even though I didn't use the `Max` solution because I need to be specific about what gets updated, I will choose this answer since it got me in the right direction.

Comment: You shouldn't find the offenders manually. You should search for them within their own table, using `count distinct(gpid)` and `group by mcust_code`. In your `update` statement you should use a subquery where you filter out the offending rows; for example with a "group by" and `having count distinct(gpid) = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Attemp 3 is correct syntactically, the problem is the data in the table: seems that `master_customer` filtered by `trading_code` returns more than one row. Is this correct? In this case there's no way to make the update you're looking for because to one single `trading_code` there can be associated different `gpid` values.

Workaround: update only in case there's exactly one single `gpid` value for all linked records:

```
 UPDATE dim_trading_accounts dta
 SET dta.gpid = (SELECT MIN(mc.gpid)
                FROM master_customer mc
                 WHERE dta.trading_code = upper(mc.mcust_code))
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gpid)   
               FROM master_customer mc
              WHERE dta.trading_code = upper(mc.mcust_code)) = 1;
```