# How to Select and Query data between 2 database in different domain?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I am trying to achieve a scenario where i have 2 database say `db1`, `db2`. Both the database have same same table `tbl1`, `tbl2` with identical schema.

My Problem is i want to select all data from `db1.tbl1` and insert into `db2.tbl2`. I need to do this with the help of scheduler running every 12 hrs.

Since i am new to sql any reference related to my solution would be helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Linked Server` or `SSIS`

Comment: May be you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

Comment: Is it possible to Schedule this task when using Linked Server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the edition of SQL Server you can try one of [Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx), [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), or [Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)