# How to find Match Records in SQL and if found then update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to loop through a SQL table and compare it to another table and if two of the columns values are a match then update the record in one table.

I have two tables `HplcData` and `DeSchedule`, `Deschedule` has all the future records that the `HplcData` table will have. I am wanting a SQL query that will look in the `HplcData` for matching records in the `Deschedule` table and if there is update the record in `Deschedule` with the data from `HplcData` and mark in done. A match is defined by having the same `BatchId` and `SampleAge`.

How can I acomplish this?

```
Hplc Data

BatchID | SampleAge | Ethanol | Glucose
7254       20          7.8       4.5

DeSchedule

BatchID | SampleAge | Ethanol | Glucose | SampleCompleted
7254       20          Null       Null      Null
7254       30          Null       Null      Null
```

So as of right now I have a trigger that does this but I need a way to reconcile the data if the trigger misses a record and I will be running this query are a windows job.

This is the query I currently use for the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_HPLC_update_details_DeSchedule] ON [dbo].[HplcData] 
    AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BatchId int, @Ethanol varchar(10), @Glucose varchar(10), @SampleAge varchar(10);
    SELECT @BatchId = bd.[BatchID],@Ethanol = [Ethanol], @Glucose= [DP1Glucose], @SampleAge = bd.SampleAge  
    from INSERTED bd
    update [dbo].[DeSchedule] SET [Ethanol] = @Ethanol, [Glucose] = @Glucose, [SampleCompleted] = 1 
    WHERE [BatchID] = @BatchId AND [SampleAge] = @SampleAge
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MERGE statement.

Something along:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.DeSchedule as Target USING (dbo.HplcData) as Source
ON Source.BatchID = Target.BatchID and Source.SampleAge = Target.SampleAge
WHEN MATCHED
UPDATE Ethanol = source.Ethanol, Glucose = source.Glucose, SampleCompleted = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the link in the possible duplicate:

```
UPDATE DeSchedule A
SET A.Ethanol = HP.Ethanol,
    A.Glucose = HP.Glucose
FROM HPLCdata HP
INNER JOIN DeSchedule DS
   on HP.BatchID = DS.BatchID
  and HP.SampleAge = DS.SampleAge
```