# Update values in one column based on another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to update `USER_FNM` in temporary table `@Users` with values from table `BAUSER`.

Table `@Users`:

```
DECLARE @USERS TABLE
(
  USER_KEY INT,
  USER_FNM VARCHAR(50),
  USER_LNM VARCHAR(50),
  USDE_HSU DECIMAL(8,2),
  [110000003] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000002] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000003] DECIMAL(8,2)
)
```

What I've already tried is this:

```
update @USERS 
set USER_FNM = (select top(1) user_fnm from bauser where bauser.user_key = USER_KEY)
```

But this always return the first value from `BAUSER` table. How to iterate over each row of `@Users` and change `USER_FNM`?

Comment: There are multiple examples on the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: Because a simple Google search of 'sql update from another table' yields various sources you could have used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports joins in update statements.
Assuming user_key is unique in table bauser, you can simply do this:

```
UPDATE t 
SET USER_FNM = bauser.user_fnm 
FROM @Users t
INNER JOIN bauser ON bauser.user_key = t.USER_KEY
```