# How to update one table from another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update table with data in another table

Table 1 `OverseasOperation` and table 2 is `ForecastTotal`

I used this command but it copy only the first value

```
Update ForecastTotal 
Set OVERSEASVol = Sales 
From OverseasOperation
```

Result is first value in `Sales` = `OVERSEASVol`

The result is

[image]

but I want to get the table like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's wrong ?

**Note**: I want to update not insert, and don't want to make condition because I want to copy all data

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL SERVER .. Added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: i don't want it based on anything

Answer (score 0):

The most generic method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
Update ForecastTotal
    Set OVERSEASVol = (select Sales
                       from OverseasOperation oo
                       where oo.?? = ForecastTotal.??
                      );
```

The `??` is for the join conditions.  It is unclear what column(s) are used to connect the two tables.

Note:  Many databases support some method of joining tables in the `update` statement.  Those methods tend to depend on the database.

Comment: i don't want to put condition so the result is .. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @AmrKamal . . . Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I Edited the question with screenshot from database and what i want

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
;with ForecastTotal_Temp
as
(
select ForecastTotal.OVERSEASVol as OVERSEASVol, row_number() over (order by OVERSEASVol) as rownum
from ForecastTotal
)

update ForecastTotal_Temp
set OVERSEASVol = (
                    select sub.Sales 
                    from (select OverseasOperation.Sales AS Sales, row_number() over(order by Sales ) as rnum from OverseasOperation) sub 
                    where sub.rnum=ForecastTotal_Temp.rownum
                  )
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: don't use where cause i want to copy all the column

Comment: but you should have connect between your tables

Comment: so why its updated with the first values .. so the error isn't in conncetion

Comment: Kamal when you set where it is where condition on yous subquery, not on your main table, so your table all data will be updated when you will understand how can you want to get data from subquery

Comment: so can u edit the answer with the sql query .. sorry for bothering u

Comment: i have change my answer, and described everething

Comment: it is miss understanding i want to get all data not only top 1 and i haven't where condition i want to copy all data in the second column

Comment: please show me your tables definition and tables some data

Comment: i added sql tables design anyway

Comment: try, i have changed

Comment: try again, i have changed something

Comment: -20
-10
-4
-3
-1
-1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
got numbers like this and this is wrong :/

Comment: that Means you have other data in OverseasOperation table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables share a unique common key (call it ukey) then

```
update ForecastTotal
   set sales = OverseasOperation.Sales
from ForecastTotal
join OverseasOperation on ForecastTotal.ukey = OverseasOperation.ukey
```

If the OverSeasOperation has multiple occurences of the primary key from ForecastTotal, then the sales must be summed,grouped on the primary key and wiill serve as the second table on the join, shown here

```
update ForecastTotal
   set sales = oo.Sales
from ForecastTotal
join 
( 
    select ukey, sum(Sales) sales
    from OverseasOperation
    group by ukey
) oo
on ForecastTotal.ukey = oo.ukey
```

Also, if you wish to update the ForecastTotal sales by adding the sales from the OverseasOperation, change the set from

```
set sales = OverseasOperation.Sales
```

to

```
set sales = sales + OverseasOperation.Sales
```