# UPDATE SQL table based on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `students` with 1000 students in. I have a query which tells me which of those students has free tuition. In the `stduents` table I have a field called `FreeTuition` and I want to populate/update that field with the results of the query. Do I need to use some kind of loop?

The `students` table has StuCode which is unique, the query returns StuCode of all the students with free tuition. This is how I want it to look:

```
| StuCode | FreeTuition |
-------------------------
| S12345  | Yes         |
| S12346  | No          |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure? I assume there is a unique ID column that you can match on?

Comment: Kindly provide data and table structure

Comment: Hi is this free tuition query from same table? If you can share the query I can give you sample

Comment: Please no loop. Inner join table and query on StuCode, and make sure query's StuCode is unique as well.

Comment: Your query seems to be similar to this [Update Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: Not enough information for a response

Comment: @Eli what more information do you need? Query returns a studentid (StuCode) and I want to populate a column in a table full of unique StuCodes whether they occur in the returned query or not.

Comment: a basic outline of what your table with the free tuition looks like (how you figure that out), and also what column you're trying to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all.  Something like this:

```
with yourquery as (
      <your query here>
     )
update s
    set FreeTuition = (case when yq. StuCode is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end)
    from students s left join
         yourquery yq
         on s. StuCode = yq. StuCode;
```

Note:  This sets the value for *all* students, yes or no.  You can change the `left join` to just `join` to set the value only for students returned by the subquery.

Comment: Excellent, spot on! Thank you!