# SQL-SERVER update table from another table in another DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL-SERVER 2012 with two DB.
I need to update the table test1 in DB1 from table test2 in DB2 if one of the columns changed.

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Tal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a syntax-

```
    UPDATE [database1]..[table1]
    SET tb1.[column1]= tb2.[column1],
        tb1.[column2] = tb2.[column2], 
        .
        .
        .
        .
        tb1.[column_n] = tb2.[column_n], 

    FROM [database1]..[table1] as tb1 JOIN [database2]..[table2] as tb2 
    ON tb1..[common_column] = tb2..[common_column]
```

[SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: can you explain me what the different between JOIN to WHERE?

Comment: here you got the answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause