# SQL Server: update column with select result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, inner-join

I have table Student with a column called IdStudent. 
The value of IdStudent is 0

Table Student also have a column called UID

I need to update  IdStudent in table Student with  IdCandidate in table Candidate.

Table Candidate also have UID column containing the same UID of table Student.

So we can do this to have IdCandidate:

```
 select C.IdCandidate from Candidate as C inner join Student as S
 on C.UID = S.UID
```

How can I update IdStudent in table Student with this IdCandidate obtained in this select?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` in update

```
update s set s.IdStudent = C.IdCandidate
from Candidate as C 
inner join Student as S on C.UID = S.UID
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using the following query :

```
update S set S.IdStudent = C.IdCandidate
    from Student S 
        inner join Candidate C on S.UID=C.UID
```

Comment: Avoid posting duplicate answers. I am not getting any difference between your and mine answer.

Comment: Please check deeply, there is difference :)

Comment: Changing table names in the clause makes difference for you, if so then why don't you answer every questions by copying others and just swapping the table names in the join.

Comment: In fact you copied! You just made the update query by copying the relation from the OP's query, but you should notice that OP's select query has the main table `Candidate`, but he wants to update the table `Student`, so the update query should have `Student` as the first table in the `FROM` clause, this is standard sql, you can learn more about these type of query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224740/5695953) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/5695953) and you can google more. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - Putting table names in correct order in `JOIN` queries is important, please see properly, the query i provided is the standard query, not the accepted one's. To learn, you can follow my above comments here.

Comment: I have visited your links but these are just answers and the standard you are talking about is not mentioned anywhere in these links. Even if it's the standard it would better not to answer by making that difference. It's my suggestion that you obey or not, doesn't matter to me.

Comment: I just answered following standard sql, the links you saw are heavily upvoted because they are useful and followed standard sql. You can do more study on it and i am sure you will agree finally. Again i just answered the OP's question, not a correction of your query.