# How to update a complete column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update a complete column of a table in shortest way possible.

I created a table with attributes

```
ID(PRIMARY_KEY),NAME,AGE,CITY_ID
```

, and inserted all the data, but later  added a new column named `SALARY`.
Now i have to insert value of `SALARY` into each tuple without using individual UPDATE statement for each tuple

```
| ID | NAME   | AGE  | GENDER | OCCUPATIONID | CITYID | salary | class |
|  1 | JON    |   25 | MALE   |            1 |      3 |   NULL |  NULL |
|  2 | SARA   |   20 | FEMALE |            3 |      4 |   NULL |  NULL |
|  3 | VICTOR |   31 | FEMALE |            1 |      3 |   NULL |  NULL |
|  4 | JAINE  |   27 | FEMALE |            1 |      3 |   NULL |  NULL |
|  6 | PRANAV |   20 | MALE   |            5 |      6 |   NULL |  NULL |
```

this is the table

Comment: What is the source of the salary data, and does it already exist in another table?

Comment: From where the salary data will come ???

Answer (score 0):

You should create a relational update query to update data to all rows from one table too another.
Ref: [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)