# select statement to return value from a different row

Tags: sql, select

I have a select query that returns these results:

```
Transaction  Type   Value
-----------  ----   -----
1            A      Null
1            A      Null
1            B      1234
2            A      Null
2            A      Null
2            B      4321
```

How would i form it so the Null values from type A get replace by the value in type B?  To get this result:

```
Transaction  Type  Value
-----------  ----  -----
1            A     1234
1            A     1234
1            B     1234
2            A     4321
2            A     4321
2            B     4321
```

Comment: Hi @dnok, show us the query. Also please tell us in which database do you work, is it Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL ? Thanks! Any information is helpful !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @dnok! Just for clarification, you want the value in type B of the same Transaction? I am not sure if in SQL you can update a value of one entry in a table with the value of another entry in the same table. But you definitely can do it if you split them into to tables: one for type A, another for type B transactions. Then join them and update .. set. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  It is Microsoft sql server and the query is just a basic select * from table.  Xealits yes I'd like the values of type B in the same transaction for the null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select transaction, type, value,
       max(case when type = 'b' then value end) over (partition by transaction) as new_value
from t;
```

If you just want the non-`NULL` value for the transaction:

```
select transaction, type, value,
       max(value) over (partition by transaction) as new_value
from t;
```

Comment: Gordon, that nailed it.  I have much to learn.  Thank you for your assistance!