# How to move a field from one table to another table and save the data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have two tables, one is about the selling, and another table contains the information about the vehicle:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle
(
    id                    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    specs_id              INT REFERENCES specs (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    model                 INT REFERENCES model (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    delivery_date         DATE,
    color                 VARCHAR(20),
    plant_id              SERIAL REFERENCES plant (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    date_of_manufacturing DATE
);

CREATE TABLE selling
(
    vehicle      INT REFERENCES vehicle (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    client_id    INT REFERENCES client (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    VIN          CHAR(17) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,**
    selling_date DATE,
    subtotal     INTEGER,
    payment      PAYMENT_TYPE,
    seller_id    INT REFERENCES manager (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

I need to move field **VIN** from **selling** to **vehicle**, and I need the existing vehicles to correspond with thier VINs. Here is the table: [The tables to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBeX8.png)

I have tried this code:

```
ALTER TABLE vehicle
ADD COLUMN VIN CHAR(17);
UPDATE vehicle VIN
SET VIN = selling.VIN
FROM selling
```

But the result is wrong: all the vehicles get the one VIN from selling:

[VEHICLE table after modifying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMFz1.png)

Comment: Your UPDATE clause needs a WHERE clause to match vehicle_id. Maybe this could be a good example for you to check out how you can write an update like that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222942/1066721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider correlating each row in `vehicle` with the corresponding row in `selling`, using the foreign key relationship:

```
UPDATE vehicle
SET vin = s.vin
FROM selling s
WHERE s.vehicle = vehicle.id
```

As this looks like a 1-N relationship, I would actually suggest:

```
UPDATE vehicle
SET vin = s.vin
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT vehicle, vin FROM selling) s
WHERE s.vehicle = vehicle.id
```