# Update only certain columns in SQL parent table from R

Tags: r, rodbc, r-dbi, rpostgresql, rpostgres

Let's say I have mtcars in a postgres server.

```
library("RODBC")
library("odbc")
library("RPostgres")
con = dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),dbname="example_db",port = 5432,user = "postgres", password = "db_password")
```

I can update the mtcars table with:

```
good_old_mtcars = data.frame(cbind("ids" = seq(1:nrow(mtcars)), mtcars))
dbWriteTable(con1, "example_db_mtcars", good_old_mtcars, temporary = FALSE, append=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

It happens that some columns may need updating. Eg. updating `qsec` with some calculation

```
good_old_mtcars$qsec = good_old_mtcars$qsec * sqrt(good_old_mtcars$wt)
```

How could I update only the `qsec` column without deleting and uploading the whole table again?

** mtcars is a parent table and the `ids` variable is used by other tables so re-uploading the whole data frame breaks other things in the database :(

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match) referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379760/multi-row-and-column-update-using-r-in-postgres-database) but it is 15 years old. Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rows_update()` with the `in_place` param set to `TRUE`, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
good_old_mtcars = tbl(con, "example_db_mtcars")

rows_update(
  x = good_old_mtcars,
  y = good_old_mtcars %>% mutate(qsec = sqrt(qsec)) %>% select(ids, qsec),
  by = "ids",
  unmatched = "ignore",
  in_place = TRUE
)
```