# Update table from (itself left join other table)

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables 
Table child : sgl_id ,student_id,  school_id , state 
Table parent : sgl_id , school_id 
Im trying to update child.state = 1 but...

```
UPDATE child
SET state = 1
WHERE sgl_id 
IN (
SELECT child.sgl_id
FROM child
LEFT JOIN parent ON child.sgl_id = parent.sgl_id
 AND child.school_id = parent.school_id
WHERE 1
AND parent.sgl_id IS NULL )
```

Comment: Please add DBMS tag, error message with this question. I think may be `WHERE 1` has the issue. you can try using `WHERE 1=1 AND...`. Or else you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match link

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)