# Trying to take column value from one table and update it into another using UPDATE & JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access, with SQL, tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)--

My objective is to use `tbl_line_items.Order_Number` and `tbl_line_items.Line_Number` as the primary keys, take the column value `tbl_line.items_Product_Line`, and update it to the `tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine`.

Basically, I want get the product line with its respective line & order number and inserting it into the MTO vs ETO table.

Current code:

```
UPDATE tbl_line_items INNER JOIN tbl_MTO_vs_ETO ON (tbl_line_items.Order_Number = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Order) AND (tbl_line_items.Line_Number = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Line) AND (tbl_line_items.Product_Line = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine) 
SET tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine = [tbl_MTO_vs_ETO].[ProductLine]=[tbl_line_items].[Product_Line];
```

My query appends, but returns nothing ("**You are about to update 0 row(s)**"). I believe I should be using the UPDATE statements as the records already exist, I just recently added that product line column for further filtering.

For nbk--

I ran a SELECT and JOIN query, and was able to successfully pull the shard order and line numbers, and find the product lines for each record. The question is now, how to I translate it over to an UPDATE query?

Code:

```
SELECT tbl_line_items.Product_Line, tbl_line_items.Order_Number, tbl_line_items.Line_Number
FROM tbl_MTO_vs_ETO INNER JOIN tbl_line_items ON (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.line = tbl_line_items.Line_Number) AND (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Order = tbl_line_items.Order_Number);
```

Comment: your set clause is funny  there should only be one = Also did you run a select with join to see if there are any row that match

Comment: @nbk I deleted the beginning of it, as I thought it was weird too, both "tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine = [tbl_MTO_vs_ETO].[ProductLine]=[tbl_line_items].[Product_Line]" & "[tbl_MTO_vs_ETO].[ProductLine]=[tbl_line_items].[Product_Line]" do the same thing for me. ;; No, I didn't try select with a join yet. I'll come back with an update.

Comment: ii added another sentence see it please

Comment: @nbk the select and join is able to find the related order and line numbers, but isn't pulling the product line item.

Comment: you have three conditions that must be met so that the row gets updated. access doesn't find any match for that three conditions, that is why i asks if you run the select with these thre on clauses

Comment: @nbk I updated my post with my select query finding.

Comment: there only 2 on conditions in the select, in your update you have 3

Comment: @nbk Ah! I got it!! I didn't know the "ON" were conditions. I took away the original product line condition from the update query and its working now. My table inserted the values.

Comment: @nbk Would you mind putting your comment in the answer section so I may accept it? "UPDATE query contained too many conditions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` has two condition

```
SELECT 
    tbl_line_items.Product_Line,
    tbl_line_items.Order_Number,
    tbl_line_items.Line_Number
FROM
    tbl_MTO_vs_ETO
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_line_items ON (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.line = tbl_line_items.Line_Number)
        AND (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Order = tbl_line_items.Order_Number);
```

but your `UPDATE` has three

```
UPDATE tbl_line_items 
   INNER JOIN tbl_MTO_vs_ETO 
   ON (tbl_line_items.Order_Number = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Order) AND (tbl_line_items.Line_Number = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Line) AND (tbl_line_items.Product_Line = tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine) 
SET tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine = [tbl_MTO_vs_ETO].[ProductLine]=[tbl_line_items].[Product_Line];
```

these three condition have to be met so that the `UPDATE` can happen

So use

```
UPDATE 
    tbl_MTO_vs_ETO
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_line_items ON (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.line = tbl_line_items.Line_Number)
        AND (tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.Order = tbl_line_items.Order_Number);
SET tbl_MTO_vs_ETO.ProductLine = [tbl_MTO_vs_ETO].[ProductLine]=[tbl_line_items].[Product_Line];
```

So that the `UPDATE` works