# How to update specific entries of table on SQL Server using data from excel

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update rows on a SQL Server table using data from an excel sheet. I want to choose the rows of the table on the SQL server to update using the Primary Key of the table (*StockCode*), but I don't want to drop the rows which I am not updating.

Below are some screenshots of the excel data headers and the SQL table headers.

There are some StockCode's which do not have a box weight. They must **remain NULL**.
The StockCode's which do have box weights must be updated using the excel data.

Here is the excel data with the first row of data:
[image: Excel Headers]

Here is the SQL Table with the first row of data:
[image: SQL Table Headers]

Comment: *"I don't want to drop the rows which I am not updating"* An `UPDATE` wouldn't "drop" the rows; a `DELETE` *deletes* rows (removes them), an `UPDATE` *updates* them (changes the values within the row).

Comment: Will this all be done on the SQL Server. How are you planning on importing the Excel spreadsheet values?

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes it will be done on SQL server. I can either use the import wizard, or import the table and make the update.

Comment: If you have a table to update from (following import) then, as Larnu suggests you can use standard SQL to update the main table. `UPDATE` will only update matched rows and you can do a `NULL` check for box weight.

Comment: please show data as text and not images. Thank you

Comment: @PeterSmith and Larnu, Thanks for the responses. I decided to do what you guys suggested, following the answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match