# Update Table1 with the help of Table2

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario :
Table1 and Table2 has same columns
=>Table1 has All data
=>Table2 has updated values except "ProductCode"(this one column remain same)

I just want to match productcode from both table and need to update in Table1

[image: table look like this]

please help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Update from One Table to Another Based on a ID Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by this -

```
Update `Table1` 
  INNER JOIN `Table2` ON (Table1.ProductCode = Table2.ProductCode)
  SET Table1.Category = Table2.Category
  ....
```

You need to give all fields to be updated.