# How to update NULL's in a SQL table using the matching values from another table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table A where I need to update the value for some rows that contain nulls in a sampling column, based on the value of the corresponding column in another table B.

Table A looks like this:

| id_col | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 003 | NULL |
| 004 | A |
| 005 | NULL |
| 006 | B |

and table B contains:

| id_col | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| 003 | A |
| 005 | B |

What I want to obtain is to update the grouping column of table A with the grouping in table B, for the matching id_col, which means that, after the query, table A should look like this:

| id_col | grouping |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 002 | B |
| 003 | A |
| 004 | A |
| 005 | B |
| 006 | B |

Comment: `JOIN` your tables. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: We need your **full** `CREATE TABLE` statements. Don't give us unhelpful cryptic names like "Table A" and "`id_col`".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match provides examples  SQL SERVER `Update.. Set ..FROM.. JOIN..on..WHERE yourfield is null

Comment: @Larnu If I join the tables I'll have two grouping columns, A.grouping and B.grouping. I need an UPDATE statement. Or if there is a JOIN statement that can change A.grouping in  place, please let me know.

Comment: *"I need an UPDATE statement."* Yes, so `JOIN` in your `UPDATE` statement. If you are getting an ambiguous column error, then make sure you alias your tables and qualify your columns. @xQbert gave you a great example in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73937832/how-to-update-nulls-in-a-sql-table-using-the-matching-values-from-another-table?noredirect=1#comment130551560_73937832)

Comment: I've read the post in @xQbert's comment and understood it :). Thank you, this can be closed.

Comment: Excellent; no wheel re-inventing