# Updating a table using another table Error in query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
UPDATE ludo_purchase_detailed_history 
SET fto_date = logs_20221002.fto_date 
FROM logs_20221002 
WHERE ludo_purchase_detailed_history.uid= logs_20221002.uid;
```

This is the error I am getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM logs_20221002 WHERE ludo_purchase_detailed_history.uid= logs_20221002.uid' at line 1

Please help me. If anyone know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: In MySQL there is no FROM clause in UPDATE syntax. Read the Reference Manual, "Multiple-table UPDATE syntax" carefully.

Comment: you require an update with a join!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I take refrence from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match

I want to update a table column using another table

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a different syntax than MSSQL

```
UPDATE ludo_purchase_detailed_history h
JOIN logs_20221002 l ON h.uid = l.uid
SET h.fto_date = l.fto_date
```